# How to eliminate Data Race even with Mutex Locks around pointer variable

Tags: go, race-condition

Some starter code goes here,

```
func (chm *ConcurrentHashMap) NFetchWorker() {
    for {
        key := <-NFetchWorkerPipe
        chm.mu.RLock()
        data := chm.data[string(key)]
        chm.mu.RUnlock()
        if data.IsUsingNFetch {
            chm.mu.Lock()
            *(chm.data[string(key)].NFetch)--
            chm.mu.Unlock()
        }
    }
}

go NFetchWorker()
```

Struct ConcurrentHashMap looks like this,

```
type ConcurrentHashMap struct {
    data map[string]DataBlock
    mu sync.RWMutex
}
```

Struct DataBlock looks like this,

```
type DataBlock struct {
    ...
    NFetch        *int32
    IsUsingNFetch bool
    ...
}
```

Now when I try to run tests with race flag enabled. I get,

```
Write at 0x00c00012e310 by goroutine 8:
  (*ConcurrentHashMap).NFetchWorker()
```

The line numbers point to this line.

```
*(chm.data[string(key)].NFetch)--
```

However I don't face this issue when I do not use pointer in DataBlock.NFetch.
But if I do that I lose the ability to make changes to NFetch directly from map without reassigning a whole new struct object to that hash in map, which would be relatively computationally expensive. I want to change the value of NFetch without reassigning the whole struct again for one small change while being free from DATA RACE. Any solutions??

Fairly New to Golang, I could be doing something really stupid here, feel free to point it out.

UPDATE: Adding Read and Write Op function

```
func (chm *ConcurrentHashMap) Get(key Key) Value {
    chm.mu.RLock()
    fetch, ok := chm.data[string(key)]
    chm.mu.RUnlock()
    if ok {
        if CheckValueValidity(&fetch) {
            NFetchWorkerPipe <- key
            return fetch.Value
        } else {
            chm.mu.Lock()
            delete(chm.data, string(key))
            chm.mu.Unlock()
        }
    }

    return constants.NIL
}
```

Write Op

```
func (chm *ConcurrentHashMap) Insert(key Key, value Value, options Options) {
    ...
    chm.mu.Lock()
    chm.data[string(key)] = Block{
        Value:         value,
        NFetch:        nFetchOld,
        Expiry:        time.Now().Add(delay),
        IsUsingNFetch: foundNFetch,
        IsUsingExpiry: foundTTL,
        mu:            mutex,
    }
    chm.mu.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: You are only locking the map, but still accessing the values concurrently. If you want locking of individual values, then you need to lock those, or only access them while holding the map mutex.

Comment: @JimB I have already added Lock and Unlock for the entire map around the decrement operation. Don't what I'm missing. If you still think somethings wrong in that snippet, do be little more specific. And also I checked other places that mutate the value of the map do use mutex locks

Comment: Exactly, you have only locked the map itself, but the individual values can still be read and modified concurrently. This is not a [mre], but seeing how you have a `RWMutex`, we must assume _something_ else is reading the value. Where does the concurrent read operation show up?

Comment: @JimB I have now updated read operation usage example. Also the testcases run write and read operation N times parallely [In case it helps]

Comment: `Get` returns the value; once that is read from the map you no longer have a lock protecting any reads or writes to that value.

Comment: @JimB Yes I'm pretty sure that is expected, after I get the value from `Get` we don't need to hold lock right?? That was my initial understanding

Comment: If you are reading and writing the value concurrently, you need some sort of synchronization. The map itself is an entirely separate value from the `DataBlock`s it contains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237101/discussion-between-nikhil-nixel-and-jimb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `CheckValueValidity` where you are accessing `NFetch` without locking it. Pointers should never be accessed without locking them.

```
func CheckValueValidity(value *Block) bool {
    if value.IsUsingExpiry && !value.Expiry.After(time.Now()) {
        return false
    }

    if value.IsUsingNFetch && *(value.NFetch) <= 0 {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

This code should work

```
func (chm *ConcurrentHashMap) Get(key Key) Value {
    chm.mu.RLock()
    fetch, ok := chm.data[string(key)]
    isValid := CheckValueValidity(&fetch)
    chm.mu.RUnlock()
    if ok {
        if isValid {
            NFetchWorkerPipe <- key
            return fetch.Value
        } else {
            chm.mu.Lock()
            delete(chm.data, string(key))
            chm.mu.Unlock()
        }
    }

    return constants.NIL
}
```